# javascript JSON array to csv

Tags: javascript, json, csv

Hey Guys i wanted to create a link which creates a csv of my JSON array.

My Code creates a CSV File every time when i reload my page 
i can't see a link, where i can click. I'm really beginner of JS

Could Someone help me?

```
var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";

        // Iterating through all the objects
        data.forEach(function (infoArray, index) {

         // Fetching all keys of a single object
         var _keys = Object.keys(infoArray);
         var dataString = [];

        [].forEach.call(_keys, function(inst, i){
            dataString.push(infoArray[inst]);
         });

          dataString = dataString.join(";");
          csvContent += index < data.length ? dataString + "\n" : dataString;
        });

        var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);window.open(encodedUri);
        var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);

        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
        link.setAttribute("download", "my_data.csv");
        link.click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used it like this
It works

```
<input id="csv" type="button" value="CSV">
```

---

```
    //--------------------------- CSV EXPORT --------------------------------

    var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
    $("#csv").click(function(){
    // Iterating through all the objects
     data.forEach(function (infoArray, index) {

     // Fetching all keys of a single object
     var _keys = Object.keys(infoArray);
     var dataString = [];

    [].forEach.call(_keys, function(inst, i){
        dataString.push(infoArray[inst]);
     });

      dataString = dataString.join(";");
      csvContent += index < data.length ? dataString + "\n" : dataString;
    });


    var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
    link.setAttribute("download", "my_data.csv");
    link.click(); 

    });
```

Comment: I dont have a heading :/ can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

you have created a link , but you need append it somewhere

for example

```
document.body.appendChild(link)
```

Comment: try <a id="link" title="CSV Export" href="#url"  download>text</a>

Comment: have you changed href="#url" to the url you need?